# How to install Pillow in Python 3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-imaging-library

i tried to install every version of pillow from the settings->Project interpreter but i get this error:

```
Collecting Pillow
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c7/04/c91bb0e495c1e8a09633ecb061fab32e276ace7cefcef5d12334cdd14cd2/Pillow-7.1.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: Pillow
  Running setup.py install for Pillow: started
    Running setup.py install for Pillow: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command C:\Users\Netanel\PycharmProjects\AutoSpotifyPlaylistCreator\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Netanel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\Pillow\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Netanel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-i4n41egn\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Netanel\PycharmProjects\AutoSpotifyPlaylistCreator\venv\include\site\python3.8\Pillow:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PdfParser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_binary.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_util.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\__main__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    running egg_info
    writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.c'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h'
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'azure-pipelines.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching '.azure-pipelines'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
    writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

    running build_ext


    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Netanel\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pillow\setup.py", line 860, in <module>
        setup(
      File "C:\Users\Netanel\PycharmProjects\AutoSpotifyPlaylistCreator\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      File "C:\Users\Netanel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Users\Netanel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\Netanel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Netanel\PycharmProjects\AutoSpotifyPlaylistCreator\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
      File "C:\Users\Netanel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Users\Netanel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\Netanel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Netanel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Users\Netanel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\Netanel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Netanel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "C:\Users\Netanel\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pillow\setup.py", line 694, in build_extensions
        raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Netanel\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pillow\setup.py", line 914, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html



    ----------------------------------------

Command "C:\Users\Netanel\PycharmProjects\AutoSpotifyPlaylistCreator\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Netanel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\Pillow\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Netanel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-i4n41egn\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Netanel\PycharmProjects\AutoSpotifyPlaylistCreator\venv\include\site\python3.8\Pillow" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Netanel\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pillow\
```

After this I tried install Pillow from the terminal and I get this

```
Collecting pillow
  Using cached Pillow-7.1.1-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (1.8 MB)
Installing collected packages: pillow
Successfully installed pillow-7.1.1
```

It took only 1 second to install but it's not really installed Pillow; I don't see the pillow files and I can't to import Pillow.

I tried everything, I tried also to install from whl file, but it have the problem like from the terminal.

I have Python 3.8 32 bit and Windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: Tips for posting here: (1) use the formatting tools provided in the editor; (2) use an English spell-checker installed into your browser; (3) use real words, this is not a chatroom; (4) use technical writing if you can. Posts here that remain open will be hosted forever, and hopefully they will be useful for other readers; on that basis, let's make them as readable and useful as we can.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your windows command prompt (by going to the start menu and typing 'cmd') and type "pip install pillow". If that doesn't work, try "pip3 install pillow". If that still doesn't work you probably didn't add pip to your PATH when you installed your Python version, so your best option at that point might be to uninstall Python then reinstall it and make sure to check the box that adds pip to PATH.

Comment: i did it bro i  checed the box in installation. and also its not the problem read again my problem

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can see the problem in the error message,

```
The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
```

Visit the below link and it says Zlib and libjpeg are required by default.

[Pillow - Building From Source](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#building-from-source)

Answer (score -2):

pip install Pillow==2.2.2
    type this in cmd